# How can I run junit test normally under spring legacy environment?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

How can I run junit test normally under spring legacy environment?

My spring project is configured as legacy.

Here, I tried to proceed with the following test.

```
package com.plx.smtst.itf.controller;

import com.plx.smtst.admin.service.POIInfoService;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml")
public class RestApiControllerTest {
// @Setter(onMethod_ = @Autowired)

// private POIInfoServiceImpl poIInfoServiceImpl = new POIInfoServiceImpl();

    @Autowired
    private POIInfoService poiInfoService;
    @Test
    public void name() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

But it produces the following error:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@7ef82753] to prepare test instance [com.plx.smtst.itf.controller.RestApiController3Test@2dd8067 ]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.plx.smtst.itf.controller.RestApiControllerTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'poiInfoService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.plx.smtst.admin.service.POIInfoService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

@Service annotation exists in POIInfoService class.
Nevertheless, test doesn't know about piInfoService.

There are various properties in my project, and I must enter `-noverify -Dspring.profiles.active=local -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in the vm option of tomcat for it to work properly. I doubt it.

In the boot project, the test worked normally even without various settings, but I don't know how to run the test normally in the legacy project and junit version 4 of this project.
How can I solve this problem?

best regards!

I tried add plugin to set JVM parameter to Tomcat like below

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-noverify -Dspring.profiles.active=local -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

but project doesn't work normally

Comment: Are you or aren't you using Spring Boot. As `-Dspring.profiles.active=local` indicates a Spring Boot property. So which is it? Also you are using an XML file, if that XML file has no component-scanning enabled nothing will be detected. So the error is probably in your `root-context.xml`.

Comment: @M. Deinum thank you for your precious advice and I will try again based on your advice! Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

The function of the @SpringBootTest second annotation is to start the Spring container. The test class without this annotation does not start the Spring container when it is running, and the container does not start, so how can it be injected through the @Autowired annotation?

Maybe you should try adding @SpringBootTest

Hope your problem can be solved

Comment: He states he is using plain Spring **not** Spring Boot, so adding spring boot annotations won't help.